# Play Services Face API - Native library not being downloaded

Tags: android, google-play-services, face-detection

I was trying to implement the demo of facial landmark detection with Google Play Services, with the Face API.
As the demo says, if the device doesn't have the native library that requires the FaceDetector to work, then calling

```
detector.isOperational();
```

where detector is of type FaceDetector would return false, and the native library would be downloaded soon (maybe when the user starts again the app it would be loaded).

But in my case, it never gets loaded, so I don't know how to fix this.

Any ideas?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

Google Vision has lowered the free storage space requirement to 500 MB in Google Play Services 8.4.  See the release notes here:

https://developers.google.com/vision/release-notes?hl=en